# Ruby: eval with string interpolation

Tags: ruby, string, eval, string-interpolation

I don't understand, why `eval` works like this:

```
"123 #{456.to_s} 789" # => "123 456 789"
eval('123 #{456.to_s} 789') # => 123
```

How can I interpolate into a  string inside `eval`?

**Update:**

Thank you, friends. It worked.

So if you have a string variable with `#{}` that you want to eval later, you should do it as explained below:

```
string = '123 #{456} 789' 
eval("\"" + string + "\"")
# => 123 456 789
```

or

```
string = '123 #{456} 789' 
eval('"' + string + '"')
# => 123 456 789
```

Comment: What do you mean by "macro substitutions"?

Comment: @sawa, i meant `#{}` sections, please , edit it in right way, I just don't know how to say it on english

Comment: Okay, maybe you meant interpolation.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What's happening, is eval is evaluating the string as source code. When you use double quotes, the string is interpolated

```
eval '"123 #{456.to_s} 789"'
# => "123 456 789"
```

However when you use single quotes, there is no interpolation, hence the `#` starts a comment, and you get

```
123 #{456.to_s} 789
# => 123
```

The string interpolation happens before the `eval` call because it is the parameter to the method.

Also note the `456.to_s` is unnecessary, you can just do `#{456}`.

Comment: Replacing the single quotes with double quotes gives a syntax error because `eval("123 #{456.to_s} 789")` is evaluated as `123 456 789`

Comment: what if the string has #{} and quotes like this: string = '12 #{45} 78 "9" 0'

Answer (score 5):

You wanted:

```
eval('"123 #{456.to_s} 789"')
```

. . . hopefully you can see why?

The code passed to the interpretter from eval is exactly as if you had written it (into `irb`, or as part of a `.rb` file), so if you want an eval to output a string value, the string you evaluate must include the quotes that make the expression inside it a `String`.